# How can I force HyperJaxb to generate toString() method?

Tags: java, jaxb, hyperjaxb

I'm trying to generate Entity classess from xsd files using HyperJaxb3. It works fine but what I need is to have toString() method in those classes. What I get is only hashCode() and equals() methods. How can I convince HyperJaxb3 to generate toString() method too?

I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out thanks to this url: 
https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/Hyperjaxb3Configuration

I just added:

```
<args>
    <arg>-XtoString</arg>
</args>
```

inside the `<configuration>` tag of hyperjaxb3 in `pom.xml` of the maven project and that made it work!